# Can I use entropy as a measure for determining significant variables in a cluster after clustering?

Tags: clustering

After clustering my data into k groups, I would like to determine for each of the clusters, which dimensions(variables) significantly describe that particular cluster. For example, lets say cluster A contains a majority of people from one age group purchasing a vehicle from particular segment. Cluster B contains people belonging to various age groups but majorly from one or two regions (out of 10-15 regions).

**Hypothesis:** Using entropy, determine for each cluster, which variables are homogeneous and use those variables to create a definition for that cluster by computing the mode (or some other descriptive statistic). For example,

**Cluster A:** Customers of 30-40yrs age group, purchasing vehicles from segment C1, etc

**Cluster B:** Customers from region R1, earning 30K-40K per annum, etc

**Are there any pitfalls of using this technique?**